# JSP Timeout Issue in Struts2

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, struts2, struts-config

I am using struts framework in which a JSP page submits form data. In Action we have a REST call to other application whose timeout is set to -1 (infinite). The request is processed at the other application smoothly. But while the processing the request in Action, the JSP page is redirected to error page which is set in struts.xml config.

What am assuming is the JSP page timeout or struts redirected to the error page because of long delay.

How can i avoid this behaviour?

Comment: Is it a user friendly behavior when user needs to wait an infinite timeout?

Comment: This -1 is actually not causing the problem. JSP page is timeout and redirected to error page.