# How to avoid page timeout in struts 2?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, timeout

Ref: [JSP Timeout Issue in Struts2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22815438/jsp-timeout-issue-in-struts2)

I'm doing a long-time job in my web application and show a warning "This could take several minutes" to the user (and a cool loading animated gif ;-).

I want my page wait until the job finishes no matter how many time it takes (no page timeout).

Thanks.

Comment: Submit a job turning cool animation first, when it finishes you receive a callback, then you can tun off the animation. You can make it sync if you animated a gif.

Comment: Hello Roman, this is not what I need. I want the user browser waiting for the time the server needs to finish the job, even if it takes several minutes, without gives the user a "Server Timeout" response. In PHP I can flush some data to keeps the connection alive...

Comment: Then you'll need to have the user set the browser timeout to something longer. Client timeouts are a *client* feature.

Comment: @MagnoC Which side is closing a connection?

Comment: I don'tn know... I access an action and then do a long job (some database calculations) while the browser is waiting. When the job is in a reasonable time, all is fine, but when it delays too much the browser gives up. I'm thinking in put this job inside a thread and tell the user to come back later to see the result becaus this can take a very long time....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also having same requirement. I used **execute and wait interceptor**. Please have lookup [here](http://struts.apache.org/docs/execute-and-wait-interceptor.html)

Comment: Cool!! Thanks so much.